# Getting index out of range when trying to call a stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset

I've got a query that is supposed to get 2 "tinyint" parameters in-order to run and I wrapped it to be a stored procedure.

the stored procedure in sql goes as follows:

```
Create Procedure query3
@X tinyint = null,
@Y tinyint = null
AS
BEGIN
SELECT T.tressure_No as 'Treasure Number', T.tressure_Name as 'Treasure Name' , COUNT( DISTINCT U.user_detail_Name) as numOfUsers

FROM dbo.tblUser AS U INNER JOIN dbo.tblTressure AS T
     ON U.country_id_user = T.country_Hidden_Code
     INNER JOIN dbo.tblListContains AS LC
     ON T.tressure_No = LC.tressure_No 
     AND LC.user_name_detail = U.user_detail_Name

WHERE U.user_detail_Name  IN(SELECT  LC.user_name_detail
                             FROM dbo.tblListContains AS LC
                             WHERE T.tressure_No = LC.tressure_No AND LC.user_name_detail NOT IN (SELECT LF.user_detail_Name
                                                                                                  FROM dbo.tblLookingFor AS LF
                                                                                                  WHERE LF.tressure_No = T.tressure_No
                                                                                                  AND LF.user_detail_Name = U.user_detail_Name)
                             GROUP BY LC.user_name_detail, LC.tressure_No
                             HAVING COUNT( LC.num_Of_List_User)>=@Y)


GROUP BY T.tressure_No, T.tressure_Name
Having COUNT( DISTINCT U.user_detail_Name)>=@X;
END
```

When I test the stored procedure in my 2008 SQLEXPRESS server R2 manager it works just fine and the query inside return's result's as expected.
but when I try to call it from my JAVA GUI it goes to hell...
here is the java code(this method is being called inside my gui to fill a table with the ResultSet):

```
public ResultSet getQuery3Results(byte numOfUsers, byte numberOfLists){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Class.forName(server);
            System.out.println("here1");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(LINK);
            String callStatement = "{call query3(?,?)}";
            pst.setByte(1, numOfUsers);
            pst.setByte(2, numberOfLists);
            System.out.println("here2");
            pst = conn.prepareCall(callStatement);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            return rs;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            rs = null;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

I get this exception stack trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setByte(Unknown Source)
    at View.ViewLogic.getQuery3Results(ViewLogic.java:1170)
    at View.ViewLogic.handleGenerateQuery3Button(ViewLogic.java:1641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have no clue what am I doing wrong, suggestion's and lead's are welcomed :D

Tom

Comment: 2 tinyint parameters is not the same as two bytes passed in.

Comment: you cannot pass tinyint from java cause this type does not exist in java, but if you pass a byte using the setByte() method, it turns the value of the byte into tinyint back in sql-server. this is from just reading the setByte() method description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line needs to happen before setting values

```
pst = conn.prepareCall(callStatement);
```

Also, you have to make sure you pass the appropriate data types according to microsoft mapping rules. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878(v=sql.110).aspx

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(LINK);
String callStatement = "{call query3(?,?)}";
pst.setShort(1, numOfUsers);
pst.setShort(2, numberOfLists);
```

Comment: Thx, that helped!!